# UIStackView - Three arranged subviews with relative widths

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistackview

I have an outer UIStackView, call it `outerStackView` with the following properties:

```
outerStackView.axis = .Horizontal
outerStackView.distribution = .Fill
outerStackView.spacing = 10
```

The `outerStackView` has three arranged subviews (think of them as 3 columns) which also happen to be UIStackViews.

I want to set the width of the three arranged subviews (columns) to be a relative multiplier of the outerStackView's width.

So I tried doing this:

```
leftColumnStackView = UIStackView()
middleColumnStackView = UIStackView()
rightColumnStackView = UIStackView()

outerStackView.addArrangedSubview(leftColumnStackView)
outerStackView.addArrangedSubview(middleColumnStackView)
outerStackView.addArrangedSubview(rightColumnStackView)

leftColumnStackView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(outerStackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4, constant: 0).active = true
middleColumnStackView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(outerStackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4, constant: 0).active = true
rightColumnStackView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(outerStackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2, constant: 0).active = true
```

This throws a bunch of autolayout errors.

How would I make these three column UIStackViews have a relative width to their parent view?

Comment: can you share with us the errors?

Comment: Looks like the spacing of 10 and the multiplier don't match. The multiplier result in 100%, this means there is no space left for the spacing.

Comment: @dasdom -  you're right, I had to take into consideration the spacing. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by giving the left and middle columns relative widths (taking into consideration the spacing between them), and the right column simply filled in the space.

```
leftColumnStackView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(outerStackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.38, constant: -20).active = true
middleColumnStackView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(outerStackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.38, constant: -20).active = true
```